# Collection name via Collections API (Solr 4.x)

Tags: solr, solr4

I'm using Solr collections API to create a collection.

```
http://127.0.0.1:8983/solr/admin/collections?action=CREATE&name=test2&numShards=1&replicationFactor=2&collection.configName=default
```

I'm expecting new collection to be named "test2" what I get instead is "test2_shard1_replica2". I don't want to tie my index name to any curent settings.

Comment: can you do some url rewriting?

Comment: It's not a solution but a very dirty hack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your collection *is* named test2.  The names you've shown there are the names of the individual cores (shard/replica) that make up the collection

Comment: Thank you, I've already realized it but this is valid answer. I had a problem with synchronization (never ending "I'm not a leader" issue) which was adding to the confusion.